# How to use If Else in OnChange() event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, dom-events, onchange

This is My HTML code:

```
<select id="stand" onchange="myFun2()">
                <option value="platinumGallery">Platinum Gallery</option>
                <option value="superHospitalityStand">Super Hospitality Stand</option>
                <option value="northWestStand">North West Stand</option>
                <option value="eastStand">East Stand</option>
</select><br><br>

<label>Cost Of Ticket: </label>
<input id="costOfTicket" type="text" readonly>
```

And JS Code:

```
function myFun2(){
    var costOfTicket;
    var selectedStand = document.getElementById("stand").value;
    if(selectedStand = "platinumGallery"){
        costOfTicket = 25000;
    }
    else if(selectedStand = "superHospitalityStand"){
        costOfTicket = 20000;
    }
    document.getElementById("costOfTicket").value = costOfTicket;
}
```

Whenever `onchange()` event occurs I want to display `Cost Of Ticket` according to the selected value of `select`. But it shows `25000` after `onchange()` event and then never changes irrespective of the values selected. How to correct the code to complete above task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me tell you. In the if-else statement, you are not comparing the values but in fact, you are ***assigning*** the values.

So change your if-else statement to:

```
if(selectedStand == "platinumGallery"){
        costOfTicket = 25000;
}
else if(selectedStand == "superHospitalityStand"){
        costOfTicket = 20000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You used `=` inside the `if` statement. You need to use `==` or `===` inside the `if statement to make it work as a condition.

```js
function myFun2(){
    var costOfTicket;
    var selectedStand = document.getElementById("stand").value;
    
    if(selectedStand == "platinumGallery"){
        costOfTicket = 25000;
    }
    else if(selectedStand == "superHospitalityStand"){
        
        costOfTicket = 20000;
    }
    document.getElementById("costOfTicket").value = costOfTicket;
}
```

```html
<select id="stand" onchange="myFun2()">
                <option value="platinumGallery">Platinum Gallery</option>
                <option value="superHospitalityStand">Super Hospitality Stand</option>
                <option value="northWestStand">North West Stand</option>
                <option value="eastStand">East Stand</option>
</select><br><br>

<label>Cost Of Ticket: </label>
<input id="costOfTicket" type="text" readonly>
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much! It was one of the silliest mistakes ever.